# Run command only between certain times, else run other command

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is change my wallpaper between certain times. For example, I have a wallpaper that I use at home, and a wallpaper that I use at school (this is a laptop). What I'd like to do is have a python script that runs a shell command that sets my wallpaper only when it is a weekday and when the time is between 08:00 and 14:15.

I'm using python 3.13 and arch linux. The part I'm having trouble on is finding the day of the week, and comparing the time. I know how to run the shell command through python(os.system('command')).

Comment: Instead of doing this using Python, why don't you use schedule a job? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for details.

Comment: In general I'd agree Andre, but with a laptop this may not be a good solution. Namely, if the laptop is in sleep mode the cron probably owuldn't fire.

Answer (score 6):

```
import datetime

day_of_week = datetime.date.today().weekday() # 0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday
time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if day_of_week < 5 and (time > datetime.time(8) and time < datetime.time(14,15)):
    do_something()
```

Comment: oops; somehow my eye slipped down to isoweekday() in the docs.  corrected.

Comment: Python allows you to do this: `... and datetime.time(14,15) > time > datetime.time(8):`

Answer (score 0):

Wooble's answer is right. If you want a slightly less efficient version but without having to remember the index of each day, you can use the weekday name (assuming your local is english):

```
import datetime

week_day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
today = datetime.date.today()
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

def change_wallpaper():
    print "Changed!"

if today.strftime("%A") in week_day and (now > datetime.time(8) and now < datetime.time(14,15)):
    change_wallpaper()
```